Understanding master-slave communication in I2C bus
When I2C bus works, both SCL (Serial Clock Line) and SDA (Serial Data Line) should be connected to Vdd via pull-up resistors. If it is a case, does it mean master or slave device actually doesn't send any electrical signals, but makes data (or clock) bits by pulling state of the line to high or low? If it is not, then what is the role of Vdd in the communication?


makes data (or clock) bits by pulling state of the line to high or low?

Only by pulling it low (or leaving it open, so it gets pulled high by the pull-up resistor). But that is what is sending an electrical signal!
The "high" and "low" voltage levels are still important to know for the other side, so having a shared understanding of what "Vdd" is is important.
